# xfce4-terminal in fluxbox follows a different style/theme to xfce4-terminal in xfce

Tags: xfce, gtk, theme, qt, fluxbox

I am using xubuntu 18.04, but this question should preferably be applicable to all linux installations having both desktop managers "xfce" and "fluxbox".

So I have started with xubuntu (i.e. ubuntu with xfce) but I have also `apt install fluxbox` as well.

In "Xfce" I use `xfce4-settings-manager` to select a theme, the result for "Adwaita-dark" theme is shown below, for the "x-terminal-emulator" application: [image: x-terminal-emulator in xfce]

However, when I switch to "fluxbox": [image: x-terminal-emulator in fluxbox]

As you can see the window's menubar, as well as the preferences window do not obey the selected theme. This is a problem in "nautilus" file manager as well, but not for other applications (such as "Thunar" file manager, which works correctly)

Does it perhaps not follow "gtk-2.0" styles ?
For that I have set gtk-3.0 in "~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini"

```
[Σettings]
 gtk-theme-name = Adwaita-dark
 gtk-icon-theme-name = SimplyGrey
 gtk-fallback-icon-theme = gnome
 gtk-font-name = Sans 10
# next option is applicable only if selected theme supports it
 gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme = true
```

I have also setup QT to use GTK+ styles, but the issue persists. What am I missing here ?

Comment: I have exactly same issue (but not in fluxbox but in xmonad), all other apps follow the Adawait-Dark theme, except xfce4-terminal, strange

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń did you resolve this problem?